# Netsuite saved search find 0 on custom column and see days in between

Tags: sql, plsql, netsuite, saved-searches

I am creating a saved search to see how long stock remained at zero before new stock came in. I created a cumulative total using formula text to give cumulative total per inventory item. To_char
I need to now find zero's for each inventory item and look at the last fulfilment date and next item receipt date to find out the number of days between last stock that was sold and new stock arrival. Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you share the table(s) and some example code that you have tried? It's difficult to answer an abstract question without some concrete examples.

Comment: Thanks @Aron. so far... criteria is.... Posting is true, Quantity is not empty, Item : Type is Inventory Item, Account is Inventory : Inventory - Finished Goods. Results tab... Item, Date, Name, Created From, Created From : Status, Document Number, Type, Quantity Formula (Text) TO_CHAR(sum/* comment */({quantity}) OVER(PARTITION BY {item} ORDER BY TO_CHAR({trandate}, 'DDMMYYYY') || to_char({internalid}, '0000000000000000009') ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW), '9,999,999,999') and field name for formula is Cumulative Total. Not sure how to do second bit to find zero and days

Comment: Are you saying where the "cumulative total per inventory item" = 0, you'd want to calculate "next item receipt - last fulfillment date"?  If so add a search result column and use this Formula (Numeric) and use summary type Max

CASE WHEN (Insert Formula for "cumulative total per inventory item")=0
THEN {filed id for "next item receipt"}-{filed id for "last fulfillment date"} END